# Why and when to divide by $\sqrt{n}$ for the confidence interval of a proportion

Tags: self-study, hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, descriptive-statistics, intuition

I was just finding a confidence interval for proportion and used:

I have $p = \frac{k}{n} $

Then to find the CI I used:

$$
p \pm z \times \sqrt{p (1 - p )} \times \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right)
$$

When It *should* have just been:

$$
p \pm z \times \sqrt{p (1 - p )} 
$$

So I'm wondering why it was that $\sqrt{n}$ was left out for this?

I'm not sure how to explain it to myself.

Comment: The standard deviation for the binomial proportion with a sample of size n does involve the square root of n in the denominator since  n p(1-p) is the variance for the binomial sum X and the estimate of p is X/n. So the variance for p is n p(1-p)/n$^2$. This is a normal approximation to the binomial proportion.

Comment: Don't  forget the correction for continuity unless .5/n is so small it can be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

(You should give details of what you're quoting -- is this a textbook solution or something?)

Whatever it is, it looks wrong (and you seem to have it right).

Let $X\sim \text{Bin}(n,\pi)$ which has mean $n\pi$ and variance $n\pi(1-\pi)$ (see Wikipedia's article on the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)). Note that $E(X/n)=\pi$ and $\text{Var}(X/n) = \pi(1-\pi)/n$ (elementary properties of [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties) and [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties)).

Now we observe $X=x$ then our ML estimate of $\pi$ is $\hat{\pi}=p = x/n$ and the ML estimate of its variance is then $p(1-p)/n$.

If we use the asymptotic normal approximation, then an approximate $1-\alpha$ interval for $\pi$ is

$p\pm z_{\alpha/2} \sqrt{p(1-p)/n}$

So the solution (I assume) you're looking at is wrong and you're correct.

Comment: If $X \sim Bin(N, \pi)$ then asymptotically it holds that $X \stackrel{asy}{\sim} Normal(N\pi, \sqrt{N \pi (1-\pi)}$.  So in the standard deviation of the normal distribution it is the ''true'' $\pi$, can we be sure that we can replace $\pi$ by $\hat{\pi}=x/N$ and still have asymptotic normality , i.e. why is it still valid that $X  \stackrel{asy}{\sim} Normal(N\pi, \sqrt{N \hat{\pi} (1-\hat{\pi})}$, do you have any references on that ?

Comment: @fcop  Let $Z=(X-Np)/\sigma_X\, {\xrightarrow {\ d\ }} \,N(0,1)$ where $\sigma_X = \sqrt{N\pi(1-\pi)}$. Now consider $Z_1 = Z/Y$ where $Y = \frac{\sqrt{Np(1-p)}}{\sqrt{N\pi(1-\pi)}}\, {\xrightarrow {\ p\ }} \, 1$ (consistency of the MLE here gives us convergence in probabiity for $Y$). [Slutsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem) then gives us that $Z_1 \, {\xrightarrow {\ d\ }} \, N(0,1)$. But $Z_1$ is just $(X-Np)/s_X$ where $s_X = \sqrt{Np(1-p)}$